# Plots next to each other

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to get two plots next to each other, but the problem is I am not able to figure out how to use a subplot in my case. The code to plot one image is pasted below.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(30, 30))
plt.title('Clean Image')
plt.imshow(clean_crop, cmap="gray")
plt.plot(clean_lr, clean_ub, 'gx', markersize=40, markeredgewidth=5)
plt.savefig("aligned_cropped_img/FCN_false_neg/" + "Img # " + str(i) + " G_cord" + str(false_neg[i]) + ".jpeg",
            dpi=100,
            bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.clf()
```

`clean_crop` is a numpy 2d array, and `clean_ur` and `clean_ub` are coordinates that I want to highlight. The second plot also has the same format with coordinates; this whole thing is in a loop.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the examples at [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html), in some of them you will find how to do that. Basically what you need to do is use `plt.subplots(1, 2)`, in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-categorical-variables-py) you can see how something similar is used to create a grid of three plots (a 1x3 grid)

So instead of `plt.figure(figsize=(30, 30))` you would have the following:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(30, 30))
```

With that you would use `axs[0]` for the first plot and `axs[1]` for the second. I would suggest you make the figure size bigger to acommodate both plots.